# Finding a textarea by content in Watir-Webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am having trouble asserting a textarea with certain content exists.
Here is an example of what I am hoping to do:

```rb
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :ff

b.goto 'http://www.velnetsupport.co.uk/parrots/FormMail/example_form.html'

b.text_field(:name => 'realname').set 'Tom Jones'
puts b.text_field(:value => /om\ Jon/x).exists? # Expect true get true

b.text_field(:name => 'message').set 'John Jones'
puts b.text_field(:value => /ohn Jon/).exists? # Expect true get false

b.close
```

Should this work? Is there another way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like a bug. Even searching by css and xpath locators seems to fail.

Answer (score 2):

One error you made above, replace text field with textarea

```
puts b.textarea(:value => /ohn Jon/).exists?
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work. Text_field is a set of inputs that include text and textareas, locating by name works so I believe value should also.

Comment: On my Linux Mint machine it's `b.text_field(:value => /Jon/)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing this, instead:

```
b.text_field(:name => 'message').set 'John Jones'

# The next line assumes you're using Rspec...
b.text_field(:name => 'message').text.should=='John Jones'

# Alternatively, if you're using TestUnit...
assert_equal(b.text_field(:name => 'message').text, 'John Jones')

# Or, do your own verification:
puts "Exists!" if b.text_field(:name => 'message').text=='John Jones'
```